# Angle between two lines in 3D when three other angles are known.

Tags: solid-geometry

I came across this while solving some optics related question. Please have a look at the image link.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4dBl.png)

So, in the diagram, lines AO and BO lie on the XY plane. I know that $\ \angle AOX=\angle BOX=\theta$, $\angle POX=\phi$ and the angle made by the plane containing the lines PO and XO w.r.t. XY plane is $\psi$. I want to find $\angle POA$ and $\angle POB$ as a function of $\theta, \phi\ \text{and}\ \psi$. In the actual problem I am trying to solve, $\theta$ is constant but $\phi$ and $\psi$ are varying. Please help me out here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s easy to see that the the unit vectors along $OA$ and $OB$ are $(\cos\theta, -\sin\theta,0)$ and $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta,0)$ respectively. Let $\hat{OP}=(x,y,z)$. Since it makes an angle $\phi$ with the $x$-axis, $$\cos \phi = (x,y,z)\cdot(1,0,0)=x$$

Now, the normal vector to the plane containing $OX,OP$ is $$\vec{n_1}=\hat{OX}\times \hat{OP} =(0,-z,y)$$ And the normal to the $XY$ plane is $\vec{n_2}=(0,0,1)$. The angle between two planes equals that between their normals, and so $$\cos\psi = \frac{\vec{n_1}\cdot \vec{n_2}}{|\vec{n_1|}}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}} =\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\ \implies y=\sin\phi\cos\psi, z=\sin\phi\sin\psi$$

From here we get $$\cos\angle POA=\hat{OP}\cdot\hat{OA} =\cos\phi\cos\theta-\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\psi 
\\\cos\angle POB=\hat{OP}\cdot\hat{OB}=\cos\phi\cos\theta+\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\psi$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I am not able to understand how the angle between the line OP and z-axis is $\frac{\pi}{2}-\psi$. I think it would have been the case if the angle OP makes with XY plane were to be $\psi$ but the case here is that, the angle $\psi$ is actually the angle between the plane containing the lines XO, PO and the XY plane.

Comment: @Kurious You’re right, I must’ve misread. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!